# How to get a fragments EditText content?

Tags: android-fragments, android-edittext, android-keypad, fragmentmanager

I have a Fragment with an EditText as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q35Xj.jpg)

After I entered something into the that EditText field, I would like to return it to the calling View. Currently I have a **wrong** logic there, with

```
public String getEditTextContent()
{
    return myEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

which does **not** make any sense, since the EditText field was not filled, when calling this..?

So my requirement:

1. Press in my parent activity Button, to trigger this Fragemnt with EditText (as in the screenshot above) (this is done)
2. I enter something into the EditText field.
3. I press "DONE" on my Keyboard.
4. After pressing done, my calling Activity is being notified about this entered content

Any hints on that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text watcher](http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example) to track edit text inputs.

Comment: 1. Then I have the String within that class, I want to have it in another class. 2. I do not want to react on all keypress, I am finished when I press "Done" on the keyboard

Comment: okke, in this case you can implement a listener to that class or simply can create a singleton class which will hold your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {           
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getEditTextContent(); // this is your method
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. Then I have the String within that class, I want to have it in another class. 2. I do not want to react on all keypress, I am finished when I press "Done" on the keyboard

Comment: I think your requirement is not clear. You clearly specified in the question that after you enter something into edit text, you would like to return it to the calling View.

Comment: Yes, but how would be the calling view/activity be notified? This is in step 1, the parent activity